# TIN Classes to a layer ARCMAP 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, tin

Just wondering if there is a method of creating a layer for each classification range in a TIN.

Another way to state my problem:
I would like to make each colour code a layer that I can "turn on and off" i.e. it will have a check box at the front.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to select parts of a TIN, since it consists of nodes rather than surfaces. Maybe someone else can fill in the details or know something I don't.

A workaround that I can think of is to convert the TIN to a shapefile ([TIN Triangle](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/TIN_Triangle/00q900000050000000/)) and from that create new layers for specific ranges (Select by attributes -> Create layer from selection).

It is possible to convert to a raster ([TIN to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q900000077000000)) and then extract parts of the raster to different grids based on the elevation. That would allow for you to turn off parts of the raster.

[Extract by attributes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000029000000.htm) (requires Spatial analyst) can be used to extract parts of a raster based on a specified value ranges. For the SQL statement, use something like

> "Value" =< 5

It appears as if decimal handling is a bit tricky, but that might just be me since my general setting is to use comma instead of point as decimal delimiter.

[image]

Now just do that for all of the ranges you are interested in to save every one of them to a new raster. After that you can turn them on and off as you please.

Just remember that raster representation differs from a TIN in detail and a few other things. If you need to do any data analysis on your data (other than visual) I would recommend that you stick to the original TIN for that. When you create your raster in *TIN to raster*, use CELLSIZE XX for the Sampling distance parameter. Replace XX with the (estimated) mean distance between your nodes in the TIN or based on the extent of your data. Typical values range from 2 meters to maybe 10-50 meters, but it depends on what you will use it for.

[image]

Comment: The Tin to Triangle is not possible as it will result in data that is not representative of the model.

Comment: I used the TIN to Raster and It is great! any help on the extract parts of the raster to different grids?  Thanks For your help!

Comment: So I have given it a go and I can get a great raster, but no attribute table...  Will persist...

Comment: So I added the information you need to get it going, I believe. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for that I have used that and I ended up with gaps between the layer ranges where they dont fit together perfectly like a jigsaw, its more like where the wrong piece is used and leaves a gap...   I have in this case continued with the TIN and as I needed present a map with the shallower ranges removed to present draw down.Thanks for your help.